# How do I delete selected rows in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagrid

I am trying to delete selected rows in a dataGrid when they hit the delete button. I want it to delete from the Database and the DataGrid.

here is how I populate the Gridbox, using Entity Framework

```
 ObjectContext objectContext3 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dataEntities).ObjectContext;
                ObjectSet<STUDENT> students = objectContext3.CreateObjectSet<STUDENT>();
                    var query4 =
                    from STUDENT in students
                    orderby STUDENT.NameID
                    select new { STUDENT.DOB, STUDENT.NameID };
                    userDataGrid.ItemsSource = query4.ToList();
                    userDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
```

Here is what I have attempted to do for deleting it. I am not 100% sure if this is even correct. If you think there is a better way, Please let me know.

```
private void deleteRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = this.userDataGrid;

        if (dg != null)
        {
            var toDelete = (IList)dg.SelectedItems;//<-- Datagrid.SelectedItems
            var collection = toDelete.Cast<DataRowView>();
            var list = new List<DataRowView>(collection);

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                item.Row.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

what errors are you getting (if any)?, try changing your list name to something that isn't used by the Net framework

Comment: Well its deleting it from the Datagrid, but it does not delete it from the Database.